# No php.ini with brew

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I installed PHP7 with brew and it said:

```
The php.ini file can be found in:
    /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/php.ini
```

but I don't see anything there. So I confirmed it with `php-fpm -i`:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.0
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/7.0/conf.d
```

I think for this reason I'm unable to run PHP scripts, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have the same issue.
Someone has already created an issue for this:

- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3599
- https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/3598

It looks like running `brew install php70 --build-from-source` does create a php.ini file. It worked for me.

Comment: Ah, a bit too late. After a full day of messing with brew I went back to MAMP 4, it also supports NGINX now.

Answer (score 67):

You can use the following command:

```
php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini
```

it will tell you what php.ini is being executed, in my case:

```
▶ php -r "phpinfo();" | grep php.ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/7.3
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini
```

Answer (score 6):

For php8 i did this:

```
cp /etc/php.ini.default /usr/local/etc/php/8.0/php.ini
```

`/php/8.0/` `php` and `8.0` directories might not exist so you have to create them

check with `php --ini` where it is looking for conf files and if any is loaded

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed PHP using brew and do not find ***php.ini*** file in ***/etc*** than search for ***php.ini.default***, this is the ***php.ini*** file. Please create a copy of default php.ini and naming it php.ini using command mentioned below.

```
sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini
```

than restart the Apache server

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 0):

This was tested in php 8

```
php --ini
```

this will list out where the php.ini file is loaded.