# How do I get Mac to install php with a php.ini file?

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, php-ini

I'm using Mac High Sierra.  I need to install php with the php.ini file installed.  I ran the following command without errors:

```
brew install php71 --build-from-source
```

However, when I search for a configuration file, I get nothing:

```
localhost:stratum-php-master davea$ php -i | grep "Loaded Configuration File"
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
```

How do I get Mac to recognize a php.ini file?

Comment: look for you ini (with in any brew) in `/usr/local/etc`  and read **[this](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-sierra-apache-multiple-php-versions)**.

Comment: After all, regardless of the final position of that file, `php -i` should print the path.....

Comment: Please show the output of `php -i | grep "Configuration File (php.ini) Path"` as well.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39659272/2908724

Answer (score 0):

If you install PHP 7.1 using Homebrew, the `php.ini` file will be generated in

```
/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini
```

You can get an example of `php.ini` [from the source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/PHP-7.1.25/php.ini-production). Alternatively, you can copy over an older version of `php.ini` to `/usr/local/etc/php/7.1/php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) says PHP will try to find config file in the same path with SAPI module.

So we should find where PHP is located: `which php`

And then copy our config file there `cp php.ini /destination/path/`